# Make sure one person can only put one input

Tags: mysql, database, ip

I want to create a website that has just one input, Username, then I will use all usernames in the database to draw a winner later.

I need to make sure one person can only write their name once and all other entries will be deleted (manually or automatically, i dont care), I just need to tell if an user posted more than one entry

Is there any way to do this?

I found this solution to get the users IP

```
 Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip' 
 From information_schema.processlist 
 WHERE ID=connection_id();
```

But then again one can use a VPN very easily. Is there any other solution?

Comment: "`Select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1) as 'ip' 
 From information_schema.processlist 
 WHERE ID=connection_id();`" That is not the websites users IP but the IP from the connecting MySQL ciient.. "I need to make sure one person can only write their name once"  Simple add a  UNIQUE KEY on the column name?

Comment: they can just use different names then

Comment: well adding a column IP is also not a good solution.. you can block out users with a static IP but there are still internet providers who are using dynamic ip's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is plenty of solutions which one by one is useless, but together they stand.
You can use IP, as you said, also add some info  to cookies/localStorage plus you may record user's browser User-Agent and some other metadata.
**The point is gather as much data as possible to determine who is who**
The more data you'll collect, the better stability will be. Good luck!